# Проблемы с Font Awesome

Tags: html, css

У меня есть статический веб-сайт там есть иконки Font-Awesome и fn-icon. У меня все нормально и с домашнего сервера и когда захожу на сайт в интернете.А вот когда с других компьютеров/планшетов т.д захожу на сайт иконок нет(квадратики там).Какая может быть проблема?
1)Мои файлы располагаются так:

- index.html
- css - style.css
- assets - font-awesome/fn-icon
  т.д.

style.css:

```
`
@import url(../assets/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css);
@import url(../assets/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css);
@import url(../assets/bootstrap-select/dist/css/bootstrap-select.min.css);
@import url(../assets/fn-icon/style.css);
@import url(../assets/Stroke-Gap-Icons-Webfont/style.css);`
```

Не могу понять в чем проблема. Прошу того кто захочет решить проблему зайти на сайт [web site](http://firesafety.az/audit)

Comment: Стиль вы подключили, а файлы шрифтов где?

Comment: Но там в font-awesome.css. Подключено  файлы в папке assets/font-awesome/fonts